# Implement challenge/response with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Is there a "best/elegant" method for implementing a challenge/response authentication, especially across multiple forms.  i.e. User initiates transaction on one form, is redirected to answer one or more challenge questions on a separate form, and then returned to complete the original transaction.

I'm in the process of implementing a third-party challenge question/response solution into our web app. Mostly, it's send information to 3rd party server, receive response, and act on that response to challenge, allow, or deny the user. With our requirements the challenge could be received either after a user has initiated a data transaction or during login, and also at other specified events. Challenging the user currently occurs on a separate form from what the user is executing.

I've been experimenting with throwing an custom event that a listener redirects to my Challenge page, but there seems to be some funkiness with the idea that I haven't worked out yet.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you need to take care of is maintaining the state of the page i.e. what exactly is involved in the transaction.

So depending on what is involved in the transaction, you can store you relevant state in a Session or querystring or a temporary table.

Once the challenge response is successful you perform the transaction e.g. saving the data from temp storage to permanent table. And if it fails, revert back the user to appropriate page.

That's the general idea.

Comment: Upon restoring the viewstate, are the relevant events fired?

Comment: Not sure how the flow is in your transactions but you can raise the events explicitly if everything is on same page. In general one way is moving the code in the eventhandler to separate method. Then you can call the method from anywhere / anytime.

Comment: I've pretty much implemented the solution from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page

But now when I've restored the page and calling the method that finishes processing, the method is called but for some reason nothing is changed on the page.  So far I've tried calling the method from Page_Load, OnLoadComplete, OnLoad, yet page changes like displaying a status message never appear.